# Is there a port knock for ASUS Merlin firmware VPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, port

I use a VPN in my ASUS Merlin flashed router and I have tried GRC's Shields Up and Zenmap (Nmap) to scan my router via another VPN to see if my VPN port in the router was open and it says stealthed/filtered. Even Shodan shows nothing on my WAN IP address. So how in the world am I able to  make a connection to my VPN when the port is stealthed/filtered? I do use a dynamic domain name if that helps.